# How to swap the position of the numbers

Tags: java, arrays, swap

I'm new to Java programming and I want to know how to swap the position of the highest number and the lowest number.

```
import java.util.*;

public class HighestandLowestNum 
{
    static Scanner data = new Scanner (System.in);

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        int num [] = new int [10];
        int i;

        System.out.println("Enter 10 numbers: ");
        for (i = 0; i < num.length; i++)
        {
            num [i] = data.nextInt();
            Highest(num);
            Lowest(num);
        }
        System.out.println("The highest number is: " + Highest(num));
        System.out.println("The lowest number is: " + Lowest(num));     
    }

    public static int Highest(int[] num)    
    {
        int highest = num[0];
        int i;

        for (i = 1; i < num.length; i++)
        {
            if (num[i] > highest)
            {
                highest = num[i];
            }
        }
        return highest;
    }

    public static int Lowest(int[] num)
    {
        int lowest = num[0];
        int i;

        for (i = 1; i < num.length; i++)
        {
            if (num[i] < lowest)
            {
                lowest = num[i];
            }
        }
        return lowest;
    }
}
```

This is my program. Please help me to fix my problem.

Comment: Sounds like homework so I'll just help you along like this. Maybe it's a better idea to return the index of the lowest and highest number instead of the value? You know how you can assign one value to another, for example: num[3] = num[6], so you could figure out how to swap two of them?

Comment: The elements in the array are user input. So it varies every time the program will run.

Answer (score 0):

Your two functions Highest and Lowest return the `value` of the highest and lowest numbers.  In order to swap them, you need to know the *positions* those values have within the array.

If you alter those functions or create new ones to return the *index* of the highest and lowest values, then you can swap them with what you've probably already seen before:

pseudocode:

```
temp = first
first = last
last = temp
```

Answer (score 0):

To Swap the two numbers in the array, you need to know the *numbers* and  their *position* as mentioned in the earlier answers. You can modify the two functions in such a way that they provide *Numbers* as well as their *Position*. One way to do this is to return an array instead of integer from the function. And in that array, information about the *number* and its *position* can be encapsulated. Ill show you what I mean in the code I am providing:

```
static Scanner data = new Scanner (System.in);

public static void main(String[]args)
{
    int num []= new int [10];
    int i;

    System.out.println("Enter 10 numbers: ");
    for (i = 0; i <num.length; i++)
    {
        num [i] = data.nextInt();
        Highest(num);
        Lowest(num);
    }

    System.out.print("The original array is");
    for (i = 0; i <num.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(" "+num[i]);

    }
    System.out.println("");

    int highest = Highest(num)[0];
    int lowest = Lowest(num)[0];
    int highestPosition = Highest(num)[1];
    int lowestPosition = Lowest(num)[1];


    System.out.println("The highest number is: " +highest+" at position "+highestPosition);
    System.out.println("The lowest number is: " +lowest+" at position "+lowestPosition);  

    //Swap//

    num[highestPosition] = lowest;
    num[lowestPosition] = highest;

    System.out.print("The new array is");
    for (i = 0; i <num.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(" "+num[i]);

    }



}

public static int[] Highest(int[] num)    
{
    int highest = num[0];
    int i;
    int index = 0;
    int[] result = {highest,index};

    for (i = 1; i <num.length;i++)
    {
        if (num[i] > highest)
        {
            highest = num[i];
            index = i;
            result[0] = highest;
            result[1] = index;
        }
    }
    return result;


}

public static int[] Lowest(int[] num)    
{
    int lowest = num[0];
    int i;
    int index = 0;
    int[] result = {lowest,index};

    for (i = 1; i <num.length;i++)
    {
        if (num[i] < lowest)
        {
            lowest = num[i];
            index = i;
            result[0] = lowest;
            result[1] = index;
        }
    }
    return result;


}
```

Try reading the modification in the Highest and Lowest functions and than go through the main code. Hope this helps.